# Why listfragment is not added yet

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-lifecycle, android-actionbar-compat

I have a list fragment, which contains in it's layout , a TextView and list (with id `@android:id/list`). In onCreate of activity, i add the fragment to the container

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Log.e(TAG, "Inside OnCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    showPdIndeterminate();
    ... /* registering some receivers */  ...
    mInstance = this;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myListFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.container);
    if (myListFragment == null) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Creating new MyListFragment");
            myList = new MyListFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, myList).commit();
        }
```

In MyListFragments' `onActivityCreated` i call a function to cahnge the textview in the layout

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(MainActivity.LIST_INIT));
        selfInterface.onTimeToChangeTitle("Fuzzy Logic Details");

    }
```

The function is

```
@Override
public void onTimeToChangeTitle(String title) {
    if (myListFragment != null) {
        // Log.e(TAG, "Inside onTimeToChangeTitle");
        if (myListFragment.isAdded()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MyListFragment added");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "MyListFragment yet to be  added");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(myListFragment).commit();
        }
    }else{
        Log.e(TAG, "MyListFragment itself null");
    }
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
    if (t != null)
        t.setText(title);
    else
        Log.e(TAG, "onTimeToChangeTitle: textview null");

}
```

After orientation change i see logs as `MyListFragment yet to be  added`, hence i tried `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(myListFragment).commit();` but this gave `cannot perform this operation here... exception`

And my probelm is as fragment is not added yet, the title is not changing, also in this case if i try to `getListView()`, this throws `list content not available exception`

How to ensure the list's view is available and is added so that changing it's contents is successful?

**Note 1**: I see `MyListFragment yet to be  added` also on re-launching the application by pressing the launcher icon after backpress.

**Note 2**: I have set `setRetainState(true)` to the fragment.

Comment: Your  myListFragment will not be null anymore. So that your code to add the fragment will not be executed..

Comment: @Sripathi, if `myListFragment will not be null anymore` then why i am getting error while trying to `getListView()`

Comment: You just debug and trace the flow of your code. I strongly hope that your code to add the fragment will not be executed because you are having the reference of the R.id.container in myListFragment(it should not be null).
 myListFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.container);
Check and let me know.

Comment: @Sripathi, i will debug and update, before that, my doubt on `code to add the fragment will not be executed because you are having the reference of the R.id.container in myListFragment(it should not be null)` is, my code executes it

Comment: do you mean that  if (myListFragment == null) condition is true? Are you getting "Creating new MyListFragment" in your log?

Comment: @Sripathi Yes ofcourse, whenever onCreate is called, i see it.

Comment: Okay give me sometime to analyze your code, will come back after that..

Comment: Can you give me the stack trace of the exception you got when you tried to attach your view?

Comment: Are you aking about `getListView(), this throws list content not available exception` ?  or the one comes due to `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(myListFragment).commit();` ?

Comment: I need the one comes due to getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(myListFragment).commit();‌​